# Swing - MaskFormatter empties my FormattedTextField when selecting another one

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to set the format to a JFormattedTextField with MaskFormatter, everything goes well until I select another field and then what was in the previous one gets deleted, how can I solve this?

Here's my test code:

```
package presentacion;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.text.ParseException;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;

public class e {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    e window = new e();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public e() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        MaskFormatter formatoNombre;
        JFormattedTextField ftxtNombre = null;
        try {
            formatoNombre = new MaskFormatter("U?????????????");
            ftxtNombre = new JFormattedTextField(formatoNombre);
        } catch (ParseException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
        panel.add(formattedTextField);
        ftxtNombre.setToolTipText("Nombre del paciente");
        GridBagConstraints gbc_ftxtNombre = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_ftxtNombre.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
        gbc_ftxtNombre.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc_ftxtNombre.gridx = 0;
        gbc_ftxtNombre.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(ftxtNombre);
    }

}
```

You can see how the text on the right side gets emptied when selecting the left side.

I need the field to just accept characters and the first one to be a capital one.

Thanks

Comment: I would guess that [JFormattedTextField#setFocusLostBehavior(JFormattedTextField.COMMIT)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html#setFocusLostBehavior-int-) is what you are looking for.

Comment: worked thank. you can post that as an answer if you want to @aterai